# How do I configure visual studio to run xUnit.net tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, xunit.net

I have configured Visual Studio 2010 to debug **xUnit.net** tests by setting the **Project Settings | Debug | Start External Program** to run the xUnit.net console runner.

This works OK but only when providing the complete path to the test project dll via the **Command Line Arguments** eg: "c:\development\TestProject.dll"

I have tried using **$(BinDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)** as parameters via the **Command Line Arguements** section but it does not work.  Any suggests on how I can avoid the explicit/full path?

Comment: Answered my own question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer was given before James' and Brad's awesome work with [xUnit.net Runners](http://nuget.org/packages/xunit.runners).  See michielvoo's answer below.

To avoid the problem of explicitly giving the library name one can use **cmd.exe** with command line arguements: **/C xunit.console.exe $(BinDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)**

Check **Use Output Window**

Use the **Tools|Options|Keyboard** configuration to assign a hot key.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I use in my .csproj file to run the xUnit GUI runner as the start action:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
  <StartProgram>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Packages\xunit.runners.1.9.1\tools\xunit.gui.clr4.exe</StartProgram>
  <StartArguments>"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutPutPath)$(AssemblyName).dll"</StartArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For this to work, all you have to do is install the [xUnit.net Runners](http://nuget.org/packages/xunit.runners) NuGet package:

```
PM> Install-Package xunit.runners
```

The only downside so far, is that it's version specific, so every time you update the NuGet package to latest, you should update this configuration to point to the correct runner.

Answer (score 2):

A alternative route is use a VS plugin as testrunner. For instance ReSharper.

Comment: an xunit testrunner for resharper can be found here: http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

I simply type the full name of the assembly thats all.

Under command line arguments: SharedDataBridge.Tests.dll